# Android AlarmManager on a ReactNative app. Is Expo the right choice?

Tags: android, react-native, alarmmanager, expo

I'm very new to the world of ReactNative and I am struggling to decide what tools to use.

Basically what I need to do is build an app that "wakes up" at a specific time each day, sortof like a standard alarm clock.

It looks like I need to take the Android AlarmManager(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) and wrap it in a js native module which I can then import.  To do this I either need to use `create-react-native-module` or `react-native-create-library`.

So far so good?

Now what I want to know is, can Expo handle this? Expo cant do background tasks so maybe not.  But then again, maybe the AlarmManager doesn't count as background work?  I'm not sure at all and I'm struggling to find straight answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can read from Expo official site which explains pros and cons:
[Why not Expo?](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Expo supports native modules just fine. And the AlarmManager might not count as a background task. But then again it might.